# Angular Type Error - __exportStar is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to setup a new frontend based on an existing app.

Receiving the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , tslib_1.__exportStar) is not a function
    at 43221 (main.js:9356:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:23:42)
    at 54756 (main.js:9827:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:23:42)
    at 55152 (main.js:14091:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:23:42)
    at 39150 (main.js:28:84)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:23:42)
    at 6517 (main.js:201979:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:23:42)
```

I have made sure that I have an updated tslib library, my package.json and package-lock.json are in line. Node modules have been cleanly installed. No errors visible throughout my editor.

Some places have said its due to an `import * as foo from 'foo'` but my application doesn't have anything like that.